# Cannot properly split strings in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split, pattern-matching

I have strings like `(x == y), (t != s), (a = b + c)`. Now, I need to get the left letters `x`, `t`, `a` and the right letters `y`, `s`, `b`, `c`.

For this I am doing the following:

```
while(//{condition}){
  eqn = stmnt.split("=");
  getVars(eqn[0])); // first while round should return x, then t, and so on. 
  getVars(eqn[0])); // first while round should return y, then s, then b, c.
}

private static ArrayList<String> getVars(String str){
    ArrayList<String> variables = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
      while (matcher.find())
      {
          variables.add(matcher.group());
      }
      return variables;
}
```

Now, this code is working well for equations like (a = b + c). For the previous two equations, it is only returning the left hand variables (x, t), but not the right hand variables (y, s).

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is this some kind of compiler? I would suggest another approach for that, then...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am trying to write a code to divide an input program code into basic blocks and then analyze the liveness of variables. Please let me know what approach you are suggesting.

Comment: Well, learn something about compilers. The easiest approach would be to use AntLR, a Java based compiler constructor. You only need to specifiy the grammar. It generates an AST automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For starters:- The second `getVars(eqn[0]));` must be `getVars(eqn[1]));`

```
while(//{condition}){
  eqn = stmnt.split("=");
  getVars(eqn[0])); // first while round should return x, then t, and so on. 
  getVars(eqn[1])); // first while round should return y, then s, then b, c.
}
```